# AngularJS - How to loop over repeat items and make a calculation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Thanks for reading / helping.
I'm a complete newbie trying to figure out AngularJS and building my first app with it. 
For this project I've created a table with textboxes (3 on a row). The data is filled by a Factory and the total per Row is calculated in the controller. This is all working fine (cost me some hours, but yay!)

Now I need to calculate a Total in the tbTotal Textbox found at the bottom of the table and i'm trying for over 8 hours now, but cannot seem to find a solution. So I hope someone will help.

I tried to get the thing going in Jsfiddle, but didnt find out how. So the project can be found at http://app.novam-it.nl/#/openkassa

at http://app.novam-it.nl/app.zip you can download the projectfiles if that would be any help

This is my repeatercode:

```
<tr ng-repeat="type in types">
            <td><input ng-change="calc()" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="type.basic"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled ng-model="type.type" currency></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-init="calc()" class="form-control total" disabled ng-model="tbTotal" currency></td>
        </tr>
```

And this is my controller at the moment

```
app.controller('openKassaController', function(currencyFactory, $scope) {
$scope.types = currencyFactory.types;
$scope.calc = function ($scope) {
    this.tbTotal = this.type.type * this.type.basic;
};
```

});

I hope someone can help me!

Regards,

Wouter

Comment: Without testing any of this, it seems like you may want to set $scope.tbTotal, not this.tbTotal. Additionally, you should probably loop over your times and add them together, not just hard code those two.

Comment: At this moment the Calc() function is working correctly. With the this.tbTotal I can set the tbTotal per row. I'm not sure what you mean with looping over my times?

Comment: I've add a zipfile with to projectfiles if you'd like to fiddle with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assigned a `total` function to each of your currency types that computes the total for that type/row.  I've also made a `$scope.total` function that loops over each type and computes the total for all rows.  The controller looks like this:

```
 app.controller('openKassaController', function(currencyFactory, $scope) {
    $scope.types = currencyFactory.types;
    angular.forEach($scope.types, function(type){ 
      //Add a total function to each row.
      type.total = function(){
        return type.type * type.basic;
      };
    });

    //Total for all rows.
    $scope.total = function(){
      var total = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.types, function(type){
        total += type.total();
      });
      return total;
    }
});
```

I've also replaced your currency directive with the built-in currency filter.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VQwmmmondQ4t8tEH0C?p=preview) showing it all working.

Comment: Nice. Is $scope.compute necessary? I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: Oops, no.  I've taken it out.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. No trying to figure out what you exactly did. Making it a learning moment. Cheers

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate a total per row:

```
...
<td><input type="text" ng-init="tbTotal=calc(type)" ... ng-model="tbTotal" currency></td>

...
$scope.calc = function (type) {
    return type.type * type.basic;
};
```